# Acquire mutex with preference for elevated process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, synchronization, multiprocessing

I have a Mutex to avoid several processes from running at same time that could be waiting to start once the Mutex is released. Now I could have some instances trying to acquire a Mutex elevated and non elevated. I would like elevated processes to be able to acquire the Mutex **before** the non-elevated processes once the Mutex is released by the process holding the lock.

Is unlikely but I'd like to consider many instances non-elevated and many instances elevated competing for the same mutex to come with something robust.

What would be a good **robust** approach to achieve that?

Solution to the problem could use more than one mutex. I was thinking I could work on that approach to separate elevated from non-elevated and play some trick.

EDIT:
I am looking the answer for Windows Vista+ mainly but the problem I think is applicable to other operating systems if we reduce the problem to process categories with priority to acquire the mutex. Would be interesting to know the solution for other OSes as well.

Comment: do you know the processes name before hand??How is the startup scenario??In linux, we have systemd,control groups exactly for this purpose, not sure about windows.

Comment: I don't know the names but I could find that information. Linux is capable of starting a process with elevation? I thought it was a Windows only thing. Ok in such case the scenario is under Windows. Would be interesting to know the *nix solution to the problem as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write code that does exactly what you want. For example, you can have a count of elevated processes waiting for the mutex, protected by the mutex. Then code non-elevated processes not to proceed until that count drops to zero. All the processes are cooperating anyway -- a cheater could refuse to block on the mutex at all. So there should be no security issues.

Comment: Very good answer @David Schwartz. Thanks. Seems the solution is around your lines. At the beginning I didn't understood well what you meant and had to organize your idea a little bit but the resulting control flow diagram based on your answer looks very robust. I am gonna use shared memory for the counter and exclusive access with a mutex as well. There could be cheating if a non-elevated process increments the counter but is not a big issue. Again thanks.

Comment: Implemented some time ago. Works very nicely.